# Carga de CSV Centos 7 problemas PHP

Tags: php, apache, csv, permisos, centos

Buenas, tengo un archivo CSV que contiene esta configuración:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$allowed = array('csv');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    $message = 'Archivo invalido, porfavor usa un archivo .CSV!';
} else {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    $file = "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
     INTO TABLE documento
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (titulo_documento,proyecto,estado,idioma,num_documento,version,revision,descripcion,fecha,subcategoria,confidencialidad,tipo_documento,acro_usuario,aprobado_por,autorizado_por,revisor,compania,codigo_proyecto)
eof;
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $message = "CSV importado correctamente!";
}
}
```

Y tengo estos permisos en el Server de Centos en la carpeta "files/"

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache  4096 jul 21 10:34 files
```

Y si pruebo todo esto en un "Xampp" en local en Windows funciona perfectamente, si no esta el archivo lo sube y seguidamente lo carga y aquí en Centos 7 me indica:

```
Can't find file 'files/Documento2.csv'.
```

Comment: Prueba por descartar con un archivo cuyo nombre no tenga mayúsculas.

Comment: ¿Donde tienes la carpeta files?

Comment: Can't find file 'files/kjbvgyugty.csv'. Es decir tampoco, la carpeta file esta al mismo nivel que el archivo que carga los CSv, por eso le indique "files/". Si el archivo esta en el server lo carga perfectamente, es decir, el fallo es que no llega a mover el documento a la ruta especificada

Comment: Haz un `find -name archivo.csv` donde archivo es el fichero que tendria que haber subido. Mira a ver si aparece en cualquiero otra ruta. Existe la posibilidad de que la ruta raiz para tu servidor este apuntando de distinta forma en Windows que en CentOS

Comment: find -name Documento2.csv y locate Documento2.csv y no encuentra nada en el server, sin embargo busco cosas que se, que si estan y saca las rutas. El kit de la cuestión es: Si yo subo por WINSCP el archivo lo encuentra por que claro en el Server ya esta subido, pero subirlo a si a pelo no es capaz, asi que falla lo de subir y no lo de importar, por que si ya esta subido lo importa correctamente

Comment: ¿No será que lo crea en `/` directamente? ¿O en `/var/www/`?

Comment: Me pasaba algo parecido en un servidor de Ubuntu y lo que faltaba era habilitar en mi caso la extensión php_fileinfo . Esa información sale en los logs. Revisa los logs para ver si te indica algo más sobre el problema.

Comment: fedorqui, peor hci eun locate y no encuentra el archivo en el server, y si pongo la ruta completa tampoco funciona

Comment: [Fri Jul 21 13:17:12.904646 2017] [php7:warn] [pid 20586] [client 172.27.1.16:62401] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpAkXtPM' to 'files/Documento2.csv' in /var/www/dcmcode/vista/Tablas/Import/documento.php on line 31, referer: http://dcmcode/Tablas/Import/documento.php ///la línea 31 //   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name']); // Dice permisos denegados, pero los permisos los tiene apache con 777

Comment: ¿A quién pertenece el directorio `/var/www/dcmcode/vista/Tablas/Import/` y para arriba?

Comment: /var root
/www root
/dcmcode root
/vista root
/Tablas root
/import hacia arriba que solo contiene /files apache

Comment: Pues monte otro servidor y le di acceso a todos los equipos de mi casa, y funciona correctamente, el Lunes al llegar a la oficina se lo enseñare a los Administradores de Sistemas el fallo debe de ser en sus servidores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es de permisos, ¿como tienes configurado ese servidor Apache?

Veo que tienes el usuario `apache:apache` que entiendo que lo haces para poder ejecutar PHP mediante el servidor Apache.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es ponerte `PHP-FPM` de manera que sea el mismo usuario que estés usando para "buscar" y ejecutar `PHP`, y el que usas como `shell`

Aquí tienes un manual sencillo de como instalar PHP-FPM en [Centos6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) y [Centos7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7)

Si una vez tengas correctos los permisos, te sigue dando errores, me comentas y miramos otras alternativas.

Comment: En cuanto lo instale empezo a funcionar todo, muhcisimas gracias, algo había leido del `PHP-FPM` pero no quise hacer nada pero fue la solución, de nuevo, Gracias.